# Bind VB.NET WPF DataGrid and ListBox to display XML content

Tags: xml, wpf, vb.net, binding

I am trying to display in a WPF DataGrid some data coming from a XML file (3 columns in the following example) based on the selection in a ListBox, which displays one field of the same XML file.

With the following code the DataGrid remains miserably empty... :-(

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <XmlDataProvider x:Key="XmlData" Source="E:\CMT\Automation\Testarea\Authors.xml"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ListBox Name="ListBox1" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource XmlData}, XPath=Authors_Table/authors}" DisplayMemberPath="au_id" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="202" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="129"/>
    <DataGrid DataContext="{Binding ElementName=ListBox1, XPath=SelectedItem}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="155,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="202" Width="353">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="FNameCol" Binding="{Binding XPath=au_fname}" Header="First Name"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="LNameCol" Binding="{Binding XPath=au_lname}" Header="Last Name"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="PhoneCol" Binding="{Binding XPath=phone}" Header="Phone"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

The XML file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Authors_Table>
  <authors>
    <au_id>172-32-1176</au_id>
    <au_lname>White</au_lname>
    <au_fname>Johnson</au_fname>
    <phone>408 496-7223</phone>
    <address>10932 Bigge Rd.</address>
    <city>Menlo Park</city>
    <state>CA</state>
    <zip>94025</zip>
    <contract>true</contract>
  </authors>
```

Comment: Cool. What's your question?

Comment: @user3816869 leaving binding errors aside `ListBox.SelectedItem` will give your single `authors` node. What do you want to display in `DataGrid` since there's only one row?

Comment: :-) I have a XML file with many more entries (I just gave one entry as an example to show the structure of the file). I'd like to display in a ListBox the au_id (for example) and the remaining information (all or some other fields of the XML file) in the DataGrid. And I'd like the DataGrid's content to change based on the selection in the ListBox.

Comment: but at the moment you try to bind `DataGrid` to `ListBox.SelectedItem` which, not matter how many items you have in XML, will give you single selected item

Comment: True and this is what I want. I want to select one item in the ListBox and populate the DataGrid with the information related to this item. Typically I select the au_id of one author and I expect to see in the DataGrid the au_lname, au_fname and phone information corresponding to the selected au_id. You are right that in that case I will see only one row, and it is OK. This example is just one small test case to figure out how to do the binding. In the real case, it will be more complicated with multiple rows. Thanks.